# Assumption of solutions in partial differential equations

Tags: electrostatics, potential, differential-equations, linear-systems

In Griffiths' *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, in all the problems regarding calculation of potential within grounded metal pipes and plates, while solving [Laplace's Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation), the solution has been assumed to be a product of functions of $x$ and $y$. It has been highlighted in the figure below. Griffiths himself has written that the assumption is totally absurd.

[image]

**My question is:**

Why do we make such an assumption which only gives us *special* solution? Why don't we go for a general solution using some standard procedure of solving the pde?Is there some kind of advantage of using this type of an assumption?

Comment: Because otherwise the problem is very hard, because you _actually_ have to solve a partial differential equation. When it separates, we just get ordinary differential equations.

Comment: @knzhou But then we get just a tiny subset of all possible solutions. Isn't that something to worry about?

Comment: It's in your post **By pasting them together, we get a general solution**

Comment: @count_to_10:  Not just **a** general solution, **the** general solution.  Uniqueness is important here;  as Griffiths himself says (p. 120 of the 4th ed.), "The uniqueness theorem is a license to your imagination.  It doesn't matter *how* you come by your solution;  if (a) it satisfies Laplace's equation and (b) it has the correct value on the boundaries, then it's *right*."

Comment: You should carry on reading, cause the writer will justify his assumption couple of pages later. The trick is that, this is a linear PDE, so if you have two solutions, their summation is also a solution. you get as a particular solution sines and cosines, when you combine them together you get a Fourier series which allow you to express the general solution.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert thanks Michael,  I should have spotted that.

Answer (score 2):

For linear, partial differential equations (wave equation, Fourier's heat equation, Schrödinger equation, diffusion equation (Fick's second law), convective diffusion equation and quite a few others) the *method of separation of variables* seems to always work (and can be adapted even for equations with source terms, i.e. non-homogenous PDEs).

If a function $u(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)$ is sought then the Ansatz is a function:

$$u(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n)=X_1(x_1)X_2(x_2)X_3(x_3)...X_n(x_n)$$

Inserting the Ansatz in the original PDE and minimal reworking then allows separation of variables in the form of a number of ODEs:

$$f_1[X_1(x_1)]=f_2[X_2(x_2)]+f_3[X_3(x_3)]+...+f_n[X_n(x_n)]$$

Introducing a separation constant like $-m^2$ then gives:

$$f_1[X_1(x_1)]=f_2[X_2(x_2)]+f_3[X_3(x_3)]+...+f_n[X_n(x_n)]=-m^2$$

We then solve $f_1[X_1(x_1)]=-m^2$ using relevant boundary conditions. Once $-m^2$ is determined we can also write:

$$f_2[X_2(x_2)]=-m^2-f_3[X_3(x_3)]-...-f_n[X_n(x_n)]=-o^2$$

So we can solve:

$$f_2[X_2(x_2)]=-o^2$$

The process is repeated for all variables.

[A nice example is my answer to this SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/270473/integer-number-of-wavelengths-after-the-wavefunction-is-normalized-in-a-cubic-bo/270477#270477).

Another step-by-step example: [wave equation for an elastic string](http://www.sciencemadness.org/talk/viewthread.php?tid=65532&page=17#pid451284).

**Note:** the sign of the separation constant $-m^2$ has to be evaluated: it can be zero, negative or positive.

> Is there some kind of advantage of using this type of an assumption?

The advantage is that it's generally simple and seems to always work. The obtained solution can of course be easily verified by re-inserting into the original PDE.